Is there a way to unlock or bypass the Bloons Monkey City save file password?
I am trying to create a custom map for Bloons Monkey City. The Profile.Save file I have to edit to do so is a password protected archive. People have cracked the password for the jet files for the game, however the password for the save file is different. The password is NOT Q%_{6#Px]].
If anyone has cracked this password previously, please share it with me. Alternatively, is there any way I can crack this password. Tools used to break passwords for archives usually only accept .zip or .rar archives.
